# How avoid alarm dialogbox when forcing the close of a COM server

Tags: com, ole

I have a group o program written in CBuilder-xe , all with a COM interface in order to be called by a service which keep them alive and eventually restart them when they died.
The service call the module using the standard CreateObject method like here

```
varServerCom = varServerCom.CreateObject(progid);
```

All that works but I found a blocking problem.

I'm supposing, for semplicity of explantion, that I have a service program named MGR which call a serve com program called SRVCOM1.

When , for some critical probleam, The server program SRVCOM1 want to close itself it is prevent to 
close it because windows send an alarm dialogbox warning that I'm closing a program with a com reference open
and asking if I want to really close the server program.

If that program is running in background the dialogbox put the program hang indefinitely.
I want to skip this dialog box in order to avoid the hang of the program.
Is possible tell to windows , or to the server com to accept alway a force closing of the server program ?

Comment: Murphy at work again.  Every hack around a known bug that doesn't actually fix the bug just adds more ways to cause failure.  That message box is the least of your problem, you'll also crash all the client processes that connected to the server.  Short from finding the line of code that displays the message box and commenting it out, you could just write another program that kills the server with TerminateProcess.

Comment: Really that messageBox, which is not call by me is a big problem, non the last one because, for example,
I see that when the dabase goes down for it's own problem my check routine restart it and the server com program 
try to restart itself to resinchronyze with the new instance of db.
All this recovery procedure should works if there wasn't such messagebox that hang the program and prevent that 
new instance will replace the old one.

And apart that, I'm only interested in discovery if there is a way to remove such nasty messagebox , not other matters.

Comment: Finding the code that displays a message box is never difficult.  Just attach a debugger, break the program and look at the call stack.  Surely you don't have to completely restart a server when the dbase goes offline?  Just recreate the connection.

Comment: @Hans, the message box that annoyed my is inside Microsoft/Ole libraries.
I haven't the source code to debug. 
I just hoped there should be somewhere the way to disable it, this was the reason of my request here.